# How do I set up the Datadog agent for aws lamda functions that spin off docker containers?

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, datadog

I'm trying to install the Datadog agent, but I'm not sure where it should reside. My company uses aws lamda functions that spin off docker containers that contain different services of ours written in GoLang. How would I go about monitoring them with datadog, and where would I install the agent? I already have the aws integration and datadog lambda forwarder set up.

Answer (score 0):

> aws lamda functions that spin off docker containers?

There are two completely separate things here as far as Datadog (or any other monitoring service) is concerned. You have AWS Lambda functions, and you have AWS ECS Tasks.

To monitor AWS Lambda functions with Datadog, I suggest reading [their documentation](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-aws-lambda-with-datadog/) on the subject.

To monitor AWS ECS Tasks, read [the Datadog documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/ecs_fargate/) on that subject. It's irrelevant that the ECS task creation is triggered by a Lambda function.